How I debug "This job failed" with no logs in Github actions?
I am learning how to use GitHub Actions, and I've got a job that builds code on three architectures.
I got the yaml labels from this page.
name: Build Artifacts

on: [push]

jobs:
  build-linux-artifact:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: make
      run: make

  build-osx-intel-artifact:
    runs-on: macos-latest-large

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: make
      run: make

  build-osx-arm-artifact:
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: make
      run: make

It works for two of them, but fails immediately on build-osx-arm-artifact.
However, the failure page does not show any logs as far as I can find.
Is there some human or programmatic way to view logs outside the GUI?
I've already tried steps documented here, but the UI is not showing me anything.

Most probably, the issue is that you're using macos-latest-large but your plan doesn't support larger runners. Replace that with macos-latest.

@Azeem Do you know if there is a way to get Intel macs on GH Actions without a large runner?

Check the available runners here. From this list, you can use macos-12 or macos-13 for AMD64.

Thanks!
I guess that means there's no Intel Mac for OSX 14 option that is not large?

You're welcome! Yes, for now, that's not available.

In our case, we did not seen any logs in the web UI either, just error: for every build step, on every run. Not sure about the cause, but, fortunately, you can also download log archives. These did contain useful information.
